# How to set custom icon for javafx native package icon on Windows using javapackager

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javapackager

I have tried setting icon using -Bicon argument using javapackager command but no luck. If i am not giving any argument then it is showing message like this "add package/windows/ to the classpath to customize".Where am i supposed to add .ico file for using custom .ico file instead of default one.Below is the sample command i am using from oracle

```
javapackager -deploy -native -Bcategory=Education -BjvmOptions=-Xmx128m 
    -BjvmOptions=-Xms128m -outdir packages -outfile BrickBreaker -srcdir dist 
    -srcfiles BrickBreaker.jar -appclass brickbreaker.Main -name BrickBreaker 
    -title "BrickBreaker demo"

Thanks,
Gurnur Singh
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change icon using javapackager by adding -Bicon="filename.ico" argument. There was an issue with .ico file which I tried first time and later I check with another .ico file and it was working fine for me.